# Loading an Angular app through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm getting an error message stating 'Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error' when loading an Angular app from a standalone PHP generated document using a Jquery Ajax/GET request.

I have Angular 1.3.15 JS loaded in the header of the document, and I load the Angular app (which is a just form with inputs the user can load if necessary using Ajax).

When the form is loaded, it works about 70% of the time, the other 30% I get the error message mentioned below.

Any suggestions why this works some of the time, but not every time?

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417 ...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to call

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
         angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('divContainingApp'), ['myApp']);     
 });
```

That did the trick :-)